# Laravel 5.2 ajax upload progress bar and TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, progress-bar, token

I'm trying to integrate progress bar on image upload. My code works fine when I submit form with PHP, but when I include javascript with progress bar I get error "TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67". This is my form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('files' => true, 'class' => 'form', 'route' => ['backend.posts.uploadimage', $post->id])) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::file('image', ['id' => 'image']) !!}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <input type="button" value="Upload Image" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="uploadImage()">
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This form generate hidden input field with token:

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="jGQWC2GljiSeZrL8wvfMaH490xHOh727345U6HzK">
```

My javascript code is this:

```
function uploadImage()
    {
        var file = document.getElementById("image").files[0];
        var id = {{ $post->id }};

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("image", file);

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
        ajax.open("post", "{{ route('backend.posts.uploadimage', $post->id) }}");
        ajax.send(formdata);
    }

    function progressHandler(event)
    {
        var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        document.getElementById("progressPercent").style.width = Math.round(percent);
    }
    function completeHandler(event)
    {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
        document.getElementById("progressPercent").style.width = 0;
    }
    function errorHandler(event)
    {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
    }
    function abortHandler(event)
    {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
    }
```

And method in my PostController for uploading image is this:

```
public function uploadImage(Requests\UploadImageRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $post = $this->posts->findOrFail($id);

        $image = $request->file('image');
        $imageName = $image->getPathName();
        $newImageName = $post->id . '-' . md5(microtime());
        $imageExtension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $imageFile = $newImageName . '.' . $imageExtension;
        $path = public_path();

        move_uploaded_file($imageName, $path . '/images/img_upload/' . $imageFile);

        $post->where('id', $id)->update(['image_name' => $newImageName, 'ext' => $imageExtension]);

        return view('backend.posts.uploadimage');
    }
```

How I can post token from hidden fields using pure javascript, or is there any other solution to solve this problem? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getElementsByName()` to get the value of input field.

```
var _token = document.getElementsByName('_token')[0].value;
//and append the value to form data
formdata.append("_token", _token);
```